# Get Maximum valued key from a Map of object values using Java8

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

I have a below map with Integer as key and Entity object as values as below

```
Map<Integer, Entity> skuMap;

Entity.java:

private StatisticsEntity statistics;

StatisticsEntity.java:

private Integer count;
```

I want to get the key where the maximum count of StatisticsEntity from the skuMap.

I got the result with below codesnippet of Java8

```
Integer sku = skuMap.entrySet().stream().max((s1, s2) -> Integer.compare(s1.getValue().getStatistics().getCount(), s2.getValue().getStatistics().getCount())).orElse(null).getKey();
```

But I want to refactor the above with `Comparator.comparingInt`, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `max(Comparator.comparingInt(entry -> entry.getValue().getStatistics().getCount()))`

Comment: Apart from the change in the way of writing the `Comparator`, `orElse(null).getKey()` would a be a problem in future when your code actually ends up with a `NullPointerExcepion`!

Comment: `Collections.max(skuMap.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue( Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getStatistics().getCount()))).getKey()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Optional<Integer> sku = skuMap.entrySet().stream()
    .max(
        Comparator.comparingInt(
            entry -> entry.getValue().getStatistics().getCount()
        )
    )
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
```

Comment: Can you add some more context around your answer?

Comment: Stack Overflow is more than a code snippet collection. Please add some explanation or guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I would've prefer one of those 2 approaches to avoid NullPointerException(in case of empty map or no statistics):

```
int max =  skuMap.values().stream().mapToInt(e -> e.getStatistics().getCount()).max().orElse(0);


Integer max2 = skuMap.values().stream().map(e -> e.getStatistics().getCount()).max(Integer::compareTo).orElse(null);
```

If you prefer with `Comparator.comparingInt`, it have a `ToIntFunction` as parameter. Input is the element you want to compare and output should be an integer - in your case count. Behind the scene,it will return exactly what you've written above `(s1, s2) -> Integer.compare(s1.getValue().getStatistics().getCount(), s2.getValue().getStatistics().getCount())`:

```
Comparator.comparingInt(entry -> entry.getValue().getStatistics().getCount())
```

Also I think all IDE suggest the replacement. In IntelliJ, I've just press Alt+Enter on your version and it suggests me the replacement with  `Comparator.comparingInt`.